# Connect secured Client with Spring Boot Admin Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot-admin

Can someone guide me how can I connect my secured client with the spring boot admin application?

Scenario: I have a spring boot application (client) with spring security and spring-actuator enabled. The actuator endpoints are secured and for this I have the following (working) configuration in my web security config:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("Test-Actuator").password("Test-Baby").roles("ADMIN", "ACTUATOR");
}
```

Now I want to integrate the Spring Boot Admin Application in our environment. I set up a simple application with `spring-boot-admin-server` and `spring-boot-admin-server-ui` enabled. In the application.properties file I provide  the following properties:

```
spring.boot.admin.username=test
spring.boot.admin.password=test
```

these are for the server admin, right?

```
spring.boot.admin.client.metadata.user.name=Test-Actuator
spring.boot.admin.client.metadata.user.password=Test-Baby
```

these are for the client, right?

Now when I run the applications I get the following error from the client: `Failed to register application as Application [...] at spring-boot-admin ([...]) 401 null`

I call the spring boot admin page and get a HttpBasic Authentication Pop Up. No credentials from above work for this Pop Up.

Note: If I disable the security in the client application.properties file it works but (like expected) the client doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Have you included `spring-boot-admin-starter-client` or `spring-cloud-starter-eureka` to register client application?

Comment: I included `spring-boot-admin-starter-client` to register.

Comment: Did you have a look at SBA 1.5. it has a chapter in the guide on this?
http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.5.1/#_securing_client_actuator_endpoints